# What is the order of Android call state change when out going or incoming happened?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

The following are the changes in phone state in android

- CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
- CALL_STATE_IDLE
- CALL_STATE_RINGING

  1. When i am making an outgoing call ,one received my call and after some time I or He ends the call.
  2. When i have a incoming call ,I received the call and after some time I or He ends the call.

Where i want to use the broadcast receiver and Listener and why service is using for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the order of android call state change when out going or
>   incoming happened?

incoming call:

```
nothing happened : CALL_STATE_IDLE
someone calls you: CALL_STATE_RINGING
call recieved:     CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
call ended:        CALL_STATE_IDLE
```

outgoing call:

```
nothing happened :                        CALL_STATE_IDLE
start a call (pressing green button):     CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
call ended:                               CALL_STATE_IDLE
```